# Website can’t be access on home network, can be access elsewhere

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

For some reason, I tried to access my website `openbayou.com` and `towersignal.com`. I can’t access my sites on my home network. I’ve done a factory reset, changed DNS to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` and still can’t access those sites. I can access my sites from another location, on my phone, and through a VPN connection.

Other computers cannot access my sites on my home network as well. When they are another network, they can be access.

```
PING openbayou.com (74.208.189.215): 
56 data bytes 92 bytes from s539887590.onlinehome.us (74.208.189.215):      
  Destination Port Unreachable Vr HL TOS Len ID Flg off TTL Pro cks Src Dst 4 5 00 5400 9c5c 0 0000 31 01 22f9 
  192.168.1.4 74.208.189.215
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What do you get when you ping openbayou.com from inside the network

Comment: PING openbayou.com (74.208.189.215): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from s539887590.onlinehome.us (74.208.189.215): Destination Port Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 9c5c   0 0000  31  01 22f9 192.168.1.4  74.208.189.215

Answer (score 1):

I unplugged both the modem and the router and let it power cycle overnight. This morning, everything is working normal.

Answer (score -1):

Your home gateway sucks and doesn't support NAT loopback (NAT hairpinning). Either find some aftermarket open source firmware distro for it that supports NAT loopback and load that, or replace it with a quality gateway that supports NAT loopback.

Comment: @JakeGould The way he phrased it made it sound to me like his servers were on his home network, not just his clients. But I see that it can be read either way. And it looks like his servers are hosted at 1and1.com. Oh well, I think I'm going to leave my answer up because it will be helpful to other people who find this question when having problems getting to their own servers on their own network.

Comment: It's looking more and more like they're hosted at the OPs location and NAT loopback isn't available because no machine on the LAN can access the sites and they work elsewhere... a router factory reset should remove any custom rules and I can't see the provider blocking anything without reason... I'm not saying you're wrong, at all, it's just the OPs symptoms are fairly consistent with NAT loopback not on/available...

Comment: Admittedly the OP's question doesn't give this all important information!

Comment: They're not hosted on the network. Hosted on 1&1.